# AMD graphics (RX 480) displaying artifacts in 17.04

Tags: drivers, amd-graphics, 17.04, visual-artifacts

The graphics card is recognized correctly and Ubuntu is using the correct drivers.

[image]
<sup>**results of `sudo lshw -numeric -C display`**</sup>

Results of `uname -a`

```
Linux Midna 4.10.0-20-generic #22-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 20 09:22:42 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I am able to reproduce two kinds of artifacts which are shown in the following screenshots.

[image]
<sup>**major screen artifacts on login and after closing**</sup>

I've had this sort of artifact happen after closing Unigine Heaven benchmark and Insurgency. **No artifacts show up when the application is running.** Highlighting the desktop around the artifacts or moving a window will fix the problem. The image linked is from boot. Artifacts that appear when closing a game will have parts of the game in them.

Most of the time, resizing windows works fine. However, sometimes the entire window flashes with artifacts. The artifacts look different from the previous image as they are more grainy than blocky.

[image]
<sup>**window resizing artifacts**</sup>

I haven't installed any video drivers like AMD's AMDGPU PRO. These bugs don't affect gameplay, but are annoying nonetheless. Has anybody else faced similar glitches with AMD graphics cards? Any suggestions on what I should do to fix it?

Comment: [Picture of window resizing artifacts](http://i.imgur.com/GLByXp3.png)

Comment: Heres the result: `Linux Midna 4.10.0-20-generic #22-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 20 09:22:42 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`